# Regular expression doesn't do the same thing in Python and in regex101

Tags: python, regex

I have an input tsv file that looks like this

```
Hornus, Jean-Michel, pasteur->->           
Diepenbeek, H. F. W., 1...-1..., capitaine->1..->1..
Grosbellet, Bernard->->        
ʿĪsa->->       
Hacquet, Pierre-François, montfortain, Le P.->->
```

I would like to have an output file that looks like this

```
Hornus, Jean-Michel->->        
Diepenbeek, H. F. W.->1..->1..
Grosbellet, Bernard->->        
ʿĪsa->->       
Hacquet, Pierre-François->->
```

I used regex 101 to build my regex and I got this one that works fine :
[^,]*,[^,]*([^\t]*)\t

My code in Python looks like this :

```
import re
fin = open("fin.txt", "rt")
fout = open("fout.txt", "wt")
for line in fin:
        line = re.sub(r"[^,]*,[^,]*([^\t]*)\t", "", line)
        fout.write(line)
fin.close()
fout.close()
```

What I don't understand is that my code removes all the lines with a comma, and my output is

```
ʿĪsa->->
```

Any help welcome !

Update :
Here is my solution, thanks to the community :

```
import re
 
pattern = r"^([^,]*,[^,]*)[^\t]*(?=\t)"
 
fin = open("fin.txt", "rt")
fout = open("fout.txt", "wt")
for line in fin:
    result=re.sub(pattern, r"\1", line, 0, re.MULTILINE)
    if result:
        fout.write(result)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `[^,]*` will optionally match any char except a comma and will also match `->` *(Assuming -> is a tab in tsv tab separated values)*

Then you capture any char except a tab, followed by a tab using `([^\t]*)\t`

But then you replace the whole match with an empty string, removing all that you have just matched.

---

You can switch the second capture group in your pattern and use both in the replacement.

```
^([^,]*,[^,]*)[^\t]*(\t)
 |                  |   
 group 1             group 2
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9XZmi7/1)

Or using a single capture group with a lookahead assering `(?=\t)` a tab:

```
^([^,]*,[^,]*)[^\t]*(?=\t)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ddY4wY/1)

Example

```
import re
 
pattern = r"^([^,]*,[^,]*)[^\t]*(?=\t)"
 
s = ("Hornus, Jean-Michel, pasteur      \n"
    "Diepenbeek, H. F. W., 1...-1..., capitaine 1.. 1..\n"
    "Grosbellet, Bernard        \n"
    "ʿĪsa       \n"
    "Hacquet, Pierre-François, montfortain, Le P.       ")
 
result = re.sub(pattern, r"\1", s, 0, re.MULTILINE)
 
if result:
    print (result)
```

Output

```
Hornus, Jean-Michel     
Diepenbeek, H. F. W.    1.. 1..
Grosbellet, Bernard     
ʿĪsa        
Hacquet
```

Comment: Thanks. I updated my examples with real world data since my lines do not always start with a letter. Even when I tweak your regex, I cannot make it work...

Comment: @Catalaburro I see, I have updated the answer.

Comment: @Catalaburro You are welcome. Note that from 15 reputation points you have the possibility to [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) all the answers that you consider useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to match:

```sh
(?m)^([^,\n]*,[^\n,]*),.*?(\t)
```

And replace with:

```
\1\2
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?m)`: Enable `MULTILINE` mode
- `^`: Start
- `[^,\n]*,[^\n,]*)`: Match 0+ non-comma, non-newline characters, followed by a `,`, followed by 0+ non-comma, non-newline characters, capture it in group #1
- `,`: Match a comma
- `.*?`: Natch 0 or more of any characters (lazy)
- `(\t)`: Match a tab and capture it in group #2

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/v9lc6c/3)

Comment: I believe the `->` in the question is meant to represent a tab, so the above needs a small modification

Comment: Thanks so much for letting me know. It has been fixed.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my examples with real world data since my lines do not always start with a letter. Even when I tweak your regex, I cannot make it work...